# Apt update stuck pointing to old Kubernetes xenial package

Tags: apt, kubernetes

Kubernetes changed the location of their repo from where they hosted it before on google. I've taken the steps to point to the new location as per K8s [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/15/pkgs-k8s-io-introduction/):

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.29/deb/ /
```

, but running apt update continues to look for a now non-existant package:

```
Err:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 142.250.72.174 443]
...
E: The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I've tried clearing the cache with apt clean, and tried reinstalling apt. Currently this is blocking not only my updates by a new program I'm trying to install with apt and its forcing the update process. Is there something I'm missing? Can't find much online other than the steps I've already done.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release, however *xenial*  or 16.04 has been EOL/EOSS for a number of years.

Comment: Run `grep "kubernetes\|xenial" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and `grep "kubernetes\|xenial" /etc/apt/sources.list` to look for duplicates of the old repos.

Comment: Thanks, there was an archive file that was tripping up apt. Much appreciated.